# Structuring my test folders/approach

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, webdriver, protractor

I have started to create a test automation for my team(Selenium and now working with protractor). I am a manual tester that is currently upgrading my skillset.

The project that I am working on is a webapp that has 2 accounts/portals. One for client and the other is admin. I've written my test in this structure

```css
test folder
---Client Tests
-----ValidLogin_test
-----InvalidLogin_test
-----ForgotPassword_test
-----other test...
---Admin Tests
-----ValidLogin_test
-----InvalidLogin_test
-----ForgotPassword_test
-----other test...
```

Now my problem is that we are now creating an angularJS app, and I need to support it. Now, I am not sure how to design it. Should I separate the platforms first then the account types? or account types first then the platform?

If there is anything that you can recommend me to study or look up to, I would appreciate your time as I am really interested on learning this for the sake of scalability.

*I decided not to include page objects in this one and the utils to make it more concise. but they are in folders within(same level) the client and admin tests folder.

Comment: Is the actual logic inside the tests the same for client and admin? Meaning, is there code duplication there?

Comment: It's up to you, whatever makes the most sense structurally (you know your application better than anyone).  With that being said - I found [this guide](https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/protractor-styleguide) to be useful (the project-structure section specifically)

Comment: @alecxe there are some logic duplicated, but they are very minimal. Only on public pages. LOg in, forgot password, signup etc etc. but inside, they are completely different

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 1 application that behaves different based on the person logging in? or 2 applications, one that the admin uses and one that the client uses?

I am a big fan of breaking test cases down into logical areas of the application, for both manual and automated test cases.  The big thing is to minimize duplicate test steps and/or code though.

Let's say you have two different applications: Admin Portal and Client App.  And I made up some areas within each.  I would suggest a breakdown similar to the following.

**Admin Portal**

**Login**

- Login - Successful
- Login - Invalid Password
- Login - Max Invalid Attempts

**Users**

- Users - Current User Info
- Users - Sort
- Users - Filter
- **Add**

  -- Users - Add - Successful

  -- Users - Add - Existing User

  -- Users - Add - Invalid Username

**Groups**

**Security**

And then I would do something similar for the client application.  Break down the folder structure based on workflows.

For the automation (protractor) tests, I'd recommend a folder structure similar to the following:
**Specs**

- Login.spec.js
- Users.spec.js

**Page Objects**

- Login.page.js
- Users.page.js

You would break down the spec/page objects files as needed based on the size/complexity of your application.  The big thing is to gain reuse out of what you can using the page objects.  The page objects would contain locators for elements on that section of the application or page and reusable functions that can be called from your spec file.  The spec file contains all the test cases.  You can think of it as a logical grouping / folder for tests.

Since you are working with an angular app, you shouldn't need to create a separate section per platform you are running on.  Each browser that you want the tests to run on should be configured with the configuration file.  If for some reason, the behavior is different on browsers, i would suggest passing in an environment variable with the test to configure which browser the test is running on and handle those particular scenarios in the spec/page objects as needed.  I would hope it wouldn't be too many of those scenarios though.